# TypeError: Layer input_spec must be an instance of InputSpec. Got: InputSpec(shape=(None, 48, 768), ndim=3)

Tags: nlp, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model

I am doing a multi -class classification task, the TensorFlow version is 2.7.0, and the Python version is 3.9. When I create a model, I reported the following errors:

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "albert" (type BertModelLayer).
in user code:
File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test_tf_2.7.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bert/model.py", line 80, in call  *
output           = self.encoders_layer(embedding_output, mask=mask, training=training)
File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test_tf_2.7.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler  **
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test_tf_2.7.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bert/transformer.py", line 209, in build
self.input_spec = keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=input_shape)

```
TypeError: Layer input_spec must be an instance of InputSpec. Got: InputSpec(shape=(None, 48, 768), ndim=3)
Call arguments received:
inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 48), dtype=float32)
mask=None
training=None
```

Part of my model code is:

```
import os
import bert
from tensorflow import keras

def create_model(model_dir, model_type, max_seq_len, n_classes, load_pretrained_weights=True, summary=False,):

"""Creates keras model with pretrained BERT/ALBERT layer.
Args:
    model_dir: String. Path to model.
    model_type: String. Expects either "albert" or "bert"
    max_seq_len: Int. Maximum length of a classificaton example.
    n_classes: Int. Number of training classes.
    load_pretrained_weights: Boolean. Load pretrained model weights.
    summary: Boolean. Print model summary.

Returns:
    Keras model
"""

if model_type == "albert":
    model_ckpt = os.path.join(model_dir, "model.ckpt-best")
    model_name = "albert_base"
    model_params = bert.params_from_pretrained_ckpt(model_dir)


elif model_type == "bert":
    model_ckpt = os.path.join(model_dir, "bert_model.ckpt")
    model_params = bert.params_from_pretrained_ckpt(model_dir)

l_bert = bert.BertModelLayer.from_params(model_params, name=model_type)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(max_seq_len,)),l_bert,
        keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0, :]),
        keras.layers.Dense(n_classes)
        ])
model.build(input_shape=(None, max_seq_len))

if load_pretrained_weights:
    if model_type == "albert":
        bert.load_albert_weights(l_bert, model_ckpt)
    elif model_type == "bert":
        bert.load_bert_weights(l_bert, model_ckpt)
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="acc")],
)
if summary:
    model.summary()
return model
```

I checked the relevant questions, and the preliminary conclusion was that the version of TensorFlow was too high, but the reason for the project cannot reduce the version of TensorFlow

Comment: Now I have solved this question, and refer to the previous answer.There are two types of input specs available in tensorflow:
<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_spec.InputSpec'> and <class 'keras.engine.input_spec.InputSpec'>
When you import the first one tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_spec.InputSpec it will give you the previous error so you have to import it from the other module:
from keras.engine.input_spec import InputSpec.